# pegar dados do input no php + banco phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html5, banco-de-dados

Como pegar estes input do html passando para o banco phpmyadmin
 **Html**

```
class="section2"  

 input type="radio"name="CumprimentoParada"id"A"value="CumprimentoParada"/>

 input type="radio"name="CumprimentoParada" id=B"value="CumprimentoParada"/>
```

**Meu php ...**

```
 $section2 =  $_POST["section2"];
```

**Meu banco conexao**

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$banco = "cadastro";
//criar conexao
$conn = mysql_connect($servidor,$user,$pass)or die(mysql_error());
;
mysql_select_db($banco)or die (mysql_error());

 $inserindo_cadastro "INSERT INTO cadastro($section2)VALUE('CumprimentoParada')";

 $resultado_cadastro    $sql = mysql_query($conn,$result_cadastro);

   echo ("Respondido com sucesso!");
```

Neste formulário ele tem uma seria de inputs rádios,gostaria de saber se estar certo a chamada php e a configuração com o banco...

Comment: Para pegar os dados do `input` no php tem que ser pelo atributo `name`. Ex.: $section2 =  $_POST["CumprimentoParada"];

Comment: aparece este erro   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in line 61

Comment: Nesta linha existe este trecho  :  $inserindo_cadastro "INSERT INTO cadastro(CumprimentoParada)VALUE('$section2')";

Comment: Teu código está meio confuso e com bastante erros!

Answer (score 0):

você deverá utilizar uma variável magica do próprio PHP, utiliza o [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php). Porém em cada "input" do HTML, tem que ter o atributo "name".

HTML

```
<div class="section2">
   <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" value="Algo..."/>
   <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="Algo..."/>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 $servidor = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "root";
 $banco = "cadastro";
 //criar conexao
 $conn = mysql_connect($servidor,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db($banco)or die (mysql_error());

 $radio1 = $_POST['radio1'];
 $radio2 = $_POST['radio2'];

 $sql =  "INSERT INTO cadastro(nome_da_coluna_1, nome_da_coluna_2) VALUE ($radio1)";

 $resultado_cadastro  = mysql_query($conn, $sql);
    echo ("Respondido com sucesso!");
?>
```

Espero te ajudado!

Comment: Em partes sim..existem mais de um inputs pra responder várias perguntas e dessa forma ele fica marcando mais de uma ...existem pergunta na section3 na section4...

Comment: no php eu posso pegar  buscando da class "section2" ?? que já pegaria os inputs que eu marcasse para cada tipo de pergunta ..Posso fazer assim ?

Comment: Se existe algo assim eu desconheço. O que você tem que fazer em cada input, é adicionar o atributo name. E no código PHP, você terá que adicionar mais variáveis. Ex:  $radio1 = $_POST['radio1']; |  $radio2 = $_POST['radio2']; |  $radio3 = $_POST['radio3']; |  $radio4 = $_POST['radio4'];

Comment: Cara do php eu entendi..só que no html se eu alterando o name= "radio1" .. outro input name = "radio2" ele vai marcar os dois eu quero que ele marque só um de 1 para 1 e não de 1 para N..isso no meu html existem N's inputs por isso dividi em classe no meu html novamente

Comment: O atributo name tem que ser igual de acordo com aquela section,eu acho que tenho que pegar ,criar uma variável php com a section pra acessar os inputs né isso ???

Comment: Sim entendi. Se em cada pergunta, você terá um grupo de radio button

Comment: Digamos que, você tem a pergunta: Qual sua banda favorita? você terá um grupo com três radio button, esses três radio button vai receber no atributo name, o mesmo.

Comment: Qual sua banda favorita? <input type="radio" name="band-rock" value="beatles"/>The Beatles
                <input type="radio" name="band-rock" value="led-zeppelin"/> Led Zeppelin
                <input type="radio" name="band-rock" value="pink-floyd"/>Pink Floy